# Matrix logical matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to get M. To do this, it is necessary for Matlab to relate column 1 of A to column 1 of ^and build a matrix M with 1 and 0 depending on whether in position [,] and ^[,] are equal to 1

```
A = [1 0 1; 0 1 1; 0 0 1 ]; 
B = [0 0 1 ; 0 1 0; 1 1 1];


for i = 1:3
  for j =1:3
    if A(i,j) == BT(i,j)  && A(i,j)==1;
       Z(i,j) = 1
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: It is the logical __AND__ operation: `Z = A & B.';`.

Comment: Are you sure about your second example case? Why would you take element `(2,3)` of A and `(2,2)` of `B.'` to build the element `(3,2)` of your output? How would you build the other elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use "`if A(i,j) == BT(i,j)  && A(i,j)==;`" you are comparing individual elements. Instead you want to be comparing columns:
`A(:, i)` and  `BT(:, j)`.

Precisely, you want

```
for i = 1:3
  for j = 1:3
       M(i,j) = any(  A(:,i) & BT(:,j)  );
  end
end
```

OR

You are comparing the columns of BT and the columns of A.

That is to say, the rows of B and the columns of A. You want to see if there are any occasions when both of the elements are 1. Thus you can compare the products of the terms in the rows of B and columns of A.

i.e. `M = logical(B * A)` should also give you the desired output.

NOTE  that the data in B are different in your image examples and in your code.